# Getting exception upon clicking Ionic based icon "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException"

Tags: android, selenium, mobile, automation, appium

I am new to mobile automation. I have a script to launch an .apk file in Android real device and perform some action upon logging in to app. But I am able to login to app successfully, but unable to perform some actions due to exception.

Steps is:
1. Launch android app in real device and login successfully.
2. Click on Create icon and enter mandatory fields.

Upon clicking the Create icon, getting the below exception.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("create_icon")).click();
```

Where Create icon is developed using ionic framework.

"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command."

NOTE: I have tried updating the ChromeDriver (ver 2.44 and 2.45), but none is useful to pass through.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Element <ion-floating-menu id="create_icon" icon="ion-plus" ng-disabled="noConection" menu-color="#0C8ED8" menu-icon="ion-plus" menu-open-icon="ion-plus" menu-icon-color="white" menu-open-color="white" menu-open-icon-color="black" ng-click="onCreateCost()">...</ion-floating-menu> is not clickable at point (0, 0). Other element would receive the click: <button id="back_btn" ng-click="$ionicGoBack()" class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item" style="">...</button>
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-45PLUD5', ip: '192.168.0.114', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```